# Using input and print in the same line in Python 3

Tags: python, input, printing

I'm creating a very simple report card program, and I'd like to be able to use the user's input to return a value.

```
print("Welcome to your report card.")
print("""You'll receive a grade point average and a class rank after inputting your grades.""")
name = input("Please enter your name.")
print("Hi,",name+".")
first = input("Please enter the name of your first period class.")
second = input("Please enter the name of your second period class.")
third = input("Please enter the name of your third period class.")
fourth = input("Please enter the name of your fourth period class.")
fifth = input("Please enter the name of your fifth period class.")
sixth = input("Please enter the name of your sixth period class.")
seventh = input("Please enter the name of your seventh period class.")

print("Great. Now we can evaluate your grades and calculate your GPA.")


firstgrade = input("""Please enter the grade you made in""",first)
```

When I run the program, I get an error message saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\New Report Card.py", line 16, in <module>
    firstgrade = input("""Please enter the grade you made in""",first)
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You *aren't* using `input` and `print` in the same line. Unlike `print`, `input` doesn't take an arbitrary number of positional arguments to show, just *one*, so you need to combine your boilerplate text with `first` *before* calling `input` with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `print()`, `input()` doesn't take as many arguments as you want to print. You have to concatenate `"""Please enter the grade you made in """ + first` or use string replacement `"""Please enter the grade you made in %s""" % first`.